# Add custom variable to APScheduler Job class

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am currently working on a web scheduler using APScheduler. One of the feature I would like to have is to create groups of tasks to be able to configure all of them at the same time on my UI.

To do so, I wanted to add a variable "group_id" in my Job instances, but I do not figure out how to do so - in the best way.

I refer to the documentation here : http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/job.html#apscheduler.job.Job

Should I pass it using keyword arguments ?

```
kwargs = {'group_id' : 123}
scheduler.add_job(...., kwargs=kwargs)
```

Is there a better way (like modifying the structure in database) ?